# StructureMap 2.6.1 injecting AutoMapper 9

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, automapper, structuremap

In a legacy project we are using StructureMap 2.6.1. I wish to inject AutoMapper 9 into it.
I am trying the following way:

```
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(m => { m.AddProfile(new MProfile()); }).CreateMapper();
For<IMapper>().Singleton().Use(c => mapper);
```

Where

```
 public class MProfile: Profile
  {
    public MProfile()
    {
      CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>().ReverseMap();
    }
  }
```

When I call

```
_mapper.Map<Person>(PersonDTO)
```

I get

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.Mapping
>   types:PersonDTO